# PHP 301 redirect based on header response

Tags: php, curl

Does anyone have any idea on how to solve this? Or if it's even possible?

PHP/curl probably?

I doubt .htaccess can handle this.

**So here's the hypothesis:**

Example URL:

https://www.example.com/category/seotools/some-seo-tool-page.html

Condition:

If the page returns a 200 header, no redirect is needed.
If the page returns a 404 header, then 310 redirect to:

https://www.example.com/category/seotools/

Note: on https://www.example.com/category/seotool/ there is very relevant information to what https://www.example.com/category/seotools/some-seo-tool-page.html used to contain. So, instead of having a default 404 it is better to 301 redirects to a page which contains relevant information to what the user is interested in.

Answer (score 0):

I think the bettere way is to use a redirect with your webserver...

For example in nginx in this snippet, if you find an error page you ll be redirect to /home.html.

```
error_page 404 /index.html;
```

I hope this help you.

regards

Comment: That wasn't the question. It's a non-sense to 301 redirect all 404s to the homepage. Thanks for your input.

Comment: Maybe you could use try_file -> check if exist the page if not redirect to second item of the function...